# assets folder cant be modified

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am trying to add some sprites to my cocos2d-x v3.0 project but I can not add any files to my assets folder in eclipse, every time I run build_native.py everything that I added to assets folder disappear.
I tried to add a folder to my project and copy my files in it but it didnt work too! the logCat gives me this error:

`05-21 09:45:26.513: A/libc(1861): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1874 (Thread-120)`

how can I add some files to my assets folder?

if assets folder cant be modified, how can I add some files (like .png files) to my project, and use it in my code?

Comment: have you checked permissions?

Comment: Yeah, my files where read only, after I fixed this problem, again I had problem with assets folder, then I found this article http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/36455?r=36466 now everything is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the contents to your assets folder directly. This will be done by build_native.sh file.

So when you need to add your images put it inside `"cocos2d-x-2.2.3\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\Resources"` and rebuild the project all the resources will be copied to your assets.

Comment: Every bit as true for 2.x (and helpful!)